# Covariance of two random variables with random parametres with a prior distribution

Tags: bayesian, covariance, prior, posterior

Let $N_1, N_2$ be conditionally independent random variables with probability distributions $Pois(t_1\theta)$ and $Pois(t_2\theta)$ respectively. Constants $t_1, t_2$ are known. The parameter $\theta$ has *a priori* distribution $Gamma(\alpha, \lambda)$. The task is to calculate $Cov(N_1, N_2)$. I am a bit confused.

I know that:
$$
Cov(N_1, N_2) = E(N_1N_2) - E(N_1)E(N_2).
$$
Should I calculate the posterior
$\pi_X(\theta) \propto \pi(N_1, N_2|\theta) \pi(\theta)$

and than
$$
E(N_1) = \int E(N_1|\theta)\pi_X(\theta) d\theta
$$

$$
E(N_1N_2) = \int E(N_1 N_2|\theta)\pi_X(\theta) d\theta = $$
$$
= \int E(N_1|\theta)E(N_2|\theta)\pi_X(\theta) d\theta
$$

Am I right?

Comment: Yes this is correct.

Comment: Thanks you very much!